# How to Write Regression Equation in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python programming. I want to write a regression program in python but I don't know how to do it.

Say I have:
`X = np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=10)`

How to define Y with the equation for Y is: Y = 3X + 6. So that it return an array of X and Y with array size=10.

Can anyone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean just `y = 3*x + 6`?

Comment: I mean, how to define Y so that it return an array of X and Y with the size=10.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the values of x and y in a single array? Like together? Or just the values of the y equation in an array different from X?

Comment: Given X as you have defined it, as a numpy array, you would write `Y = 3 * X + 6`.  Not very complicated.

Comment: Just the value of the y equation in an array with size=10, different from X. How to define the y? I know I can't write it just like this:
X = np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=10)
Y = 3*X + 6.
right?

Comment: You don't define Y.  Y will be created as the result of the equation, exactly as X was defined as the result of the randint call.

Comment: Like TimRoberts & ti7 said
Numpy can execute math-like equations directly on Arrays
Just define Y to as the equation you wrote and the result will be a numpy array with the correct values

Comment: O I see. Thank you all

Comment: What you are describing isn't regression - it's just a deterministic linear relationship between X and Y. Regression implies some degree of randomness in addition to that linear relationship. The regression process allows the determination of the coefficients that best minimise the residuals of that noise around the underlying linear relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randint(low=-10, high=10, size=10)

Y = 3*X+6

print(X)
print(Y)
```

Output:

```
[ -4   1 -10   2  -4   4  -9   0   7  -1]
[ -6   9 -24  12  -6  18 -21   6  27   3]
```

X is an numpy array which will have 10 random numbers between -10 and 10 which we have generated from np.random.randint() method. Now to find Y we can simply multiple numpy array with 3 and add 6. This will multiply 3 and add 6 to every element in X. By doing which we got above output. Each X, Y are array of length 10.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps surprisingly, you can directly use NumPy's broadcasting feature to create the `Y` array from `X` using your equation!

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.randint(low=-100, high=100, size=10)
>>> Y = 3*X + 6
>>> X
array([-80, -50,  36,  88,  -3, -98, -13,  -4,  88,  30])
>>> Y
array([-234, -144,  114,  270,   -3, -288,  -33,   -6,  270,   96])
>>> np.array([X, Y])
array([[ -80,  -50,   36,   88,   -3,  -98,  -13,   -4,   88,   30],
       [-234, -144,  114,  270,   -3, -288,  -33,   -6,  270,   96]])
```

Official docs

- terse overview
  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html#why-is-numpy-fast
- broadcasting basics and related links
  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html